# I want to communicate with a Agilent 34410a USB DMM. Too many errors

Tags: c, codeblocks

Code will not run without errors, errors start at `void main()`, then it complains about the "vi" in front of each command.

Below is my code, I am a newbe to C. Hello world runs fine. But if I try to run code below too many errors

```
#include "visa.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
     ViOpenDefaultRM(&defaultRM);
     ViOpen(defaultRM, "USB::0x957::MY47021232::INSTRU", VI_NULL, VI_NULL, &vi);
     /*Initialize device */
     viPrintf(vi, "*RST\n");
     /*Send an *IDN? string to the device */
     printf(vi, "*IDN?\n");
     /*Read results */
     viScanf(vi, "%t", &buf);
     /*Print results */
     printf("Instrument identification string: %s\n", buf);
     /* Close sessions */
     viClose(vi);
     viClose(defaultRM);
}
```

Comment: Please format the question well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us the commands to compile and link your program, and the exact error messages. You can [edit] your question (also by the "edit" link on the left below your question). But before you do that I'd like to recommend that you take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: You should start studing [tag:c] before to start coding. Where is the definition of `defaultRM`...for example?

Comment: There are definitions missing for `vi`, `buf` and `defaultRM`. What did you expect them to be?

Comment: After struggling with this code for days, I even wonder now if USB is able to communicate with C without an interface driver. Does anybody have working code that just does a simple read handshake, like DMM ID. Any help would deeply appreciated. The following code was from a GPIB interface in C.